# SELECT Values in one table that don't match another table but also reference another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I realize that probably doesn't make sense so let me try and explain:

I have two tables with the followings columns (just relevant ones):

```
positTraining (positID, trainID)
empTraining (empID, trainID)
```

The `positTraining` table contains a listing of `position ids` along with any `training ids` the position requires.

The `empTraining` table contains a listing of `employee ids` along with any current `training ids` the employee has completed.

I want to select only the `training ids` required by the position that the employee has not already completed.

So, if Employee A has completed training 1 & 3 but Position X requires training 1 & 2, I want to select the `trainID` for the missing training (2).

I hope that makes sense.

I have searched google a million different ways and checked here on SO as well but cannot find a working answer due to this extra requirement:

I want to ONLY select the `trainIDs` based on the `empID`.  Reasoning behind this is due to the fact that `empID=2` may have the correct match but `emp=1` may not.

The closest I've got all afternoon is by using the following:

```
select positID, trainID
from positTraining
except
select empID, trainID
from empTraining
```

Which returns:

```
positID  |  trainID
1        |  2
```

This is correct but only because of the current records.  As soon as another employee is put in the database with the correct match this will stop working.

I have tried using several different methods:

JOINS
NOT IN
NOT EXIST

I'm sure this is way easier than I am making it but I just can't figure it out.

Thanks for any and all help, I'll be glad to add any extra details, just let me know.

**EDIT 1**
I'm using SQL Server 2012 Express

**EDIT 2**

This is what I've ended up with, I think this is going to work:

```
SELECT 
   pt.trainID AS positTrainID, 
   et.trainID AS empTrainID, 
   e.empFirst + ' ' + e.empLast  AS empName
FROM 
   positTraining pt, 
   empTraining et, 
   emps e
WHERE 
   pt.positID = 1 AND
   e.empID = 1 AND 
   pt.trainID not in (
      SELECT et.trainID FROM empTraining et WHERE et.empID = 1)
      AND pt.trainID = et.trainID
```

Result:

```
positTrainID    empTrainID  empName
2                   2           Emp1
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What would be your desired result? Which columns, and containing what? A `positID`, `empID`, `trainID` row for each training an employee is missing to get the position?

Comment: The end result would be a listing of: Employee Name, Position Name, Name of Missing Training(s).  Given the current structure of the DB I would need to do several joins which is fine, I'm familiar with that already for the most part, just can't seem to get this crucial step.  Thanks.

Comment: what RDBMS and version are you using?. Also, when you talk about "missing trainings", you need to realize that those are valid for a particular position, or do you want to have the missing training for an employee for all positions?. What happens if an employee has more than one missing training, do you want two or more rows?

Comment: @Lamak - The employee will only have one position at a time.  Each position can have multiple trainings, so yes, there very well could be multiple rows.

Comment: @AJP - I have tried several different join attempts, I couldn't produce the desired effects so far.  I can post some examples with the results if you like.

Comment: I c your dilema.. would this work.. get all that has done train and get another set that hasn'e done training and join 2 with posit??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this would work:

```
SELECT 
   positID, trainID 
FROM 
   positTraining 
WHERE 
   positID = X 
   AND trainID not in (
      SELECT trainID FROM empTraining WHERE empID = A)
```

Considering X as the positionId you are looking for the Employee A

Comment: Actually, this came the closest to what I needed, so I've marked this as the correct answer.  Thanks!